# Trash output in 8x8x2 array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to represent a 8x8 Cartesian plane whose contents would be a string of length 2. I'd like to keep as type-safety as I can this scheme and doing this:

```c
typedef char cartesian[8][8][2];
cartesian xy;

for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                xy[i][j][0] = ' '
                xy[i][j][1] = ' '
        }
}

// The first element would represent some kind of information, and the other one 
// would be just elements like '+' or '*'. In other cases, this would be 'EMPTY',
// it means a double space.

xy[2][4][0] = 'B';
xy[2][4][1] = '+';

// The right printing method (cause it doesn't have any trash) would be:

for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++){
                printf("| %c%c ", xy[i][j][0], xy[I][j][1] );
        }
        printf("|\n");
}
```

But here's the question: Why the output trash with `printf("| %s ", xy[i][j][]);` ?
I know this could be a dumb question, but I'm out and tired now.

Thanks in advance.

By the way, doesn't work to assign. I mean: `xy[2][4][] = "B+";`.

Comment: "*a string of length 2*. Strings in C need to be NUL terminated. A two letter string requires *three* chars to store. Change `[2]` to `[3]` and ensure `xy[i][j][2]` is set to `0`.

Comment: "*doesn't work to assign*". Except when used in an initialiser, a string literal cannot be assigned to an array. Use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: At first glance, you seems to confuse the strings with the characters. There is no real string data type in C, there is only array of chracters of which the last one must be NUL. You should edit your question to add a representation of the matrix you use.

Comment: @kaylum I think `[2]`would be right one cause 2 would be to put `\0` right? In the other hand, how about this: `typedef char string[LENGHT]` and then `string str = 'This would have sense?';`

Comment: @fpiette Taken the first pair of `for` like initializer Do you mean that must do `xy[i][j][2] = NULL`? I didn't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code rewritten. Note that `cartesian` is now [8][8][3] and strcpy is used to fill the last array dimension. For clarity, I moved to clearing on xy into a separate function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char cartesian[8][8][3];

void clearXY(cartesian *xy)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            strcpy((*xy)[i][j], "  ");
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cartesian xy;

    // The first element would represent some kind of information, and the other one 
    // would be just elements like '+' or '*'. In other cases, this would be 'EMPTY',
    // it means a double space.
    clearXY(&xy);

    strcpy(xy[2][4], "B+");

    printf("-------- Method 1 --------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("| %c%c ", xy[i][j][0], xy[i][j][1]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }

    printf("-------- Method 2 --------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            printf("| %s ", xy[i][j]);
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
    printf("-------- Done ------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Absolutely clear, however I'm not clear about `[3]`. I'm assuming that `[0]` and `[1]` would be to set data and the last `[2]` would be to put `\0`. And it would be enough. Why the need of `[3]`? Even I've prove your example code with `strncpy()` and it works with 3, but 2 is the same trash output. I did that cause `strcpy()` is considered a bit warning.

Comment: @Karl, that 3 is the dimension of the char array. How many chars does each string contain? `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]` so 3 elements are required. Please note that, starting indexes from 0, accessing `arr[3]` if the size is 3 is illegal. You can access up to index `size-1`